# Get all products by category with AJAX call - Magento

Tags: ajax, magento, product

Im a newbie in magento and i have a project where the client requires to have a custom page to list all products and filter them via Categories(dropdown list of categories). When a category is chosen from the dropdown, the product list should be updated without reloading the page. In the programming side, once the category is chosen, i will call a url/function of magento via ajax and pass category id ass post/get parameter. The response of the call should be a json.

Ive been researching a while but seems like most of the examples need page reloading.

Can you give me idea or code snippets on what function/url to call as my starting point?

I have not tried anything so far but i know how the logic works. It;s just that i dont know where to get started.

Hopefully someone can lead me to the right direction.

Any little help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Magento uses Prototype JS library.  It has the AJAX object included.  You can add event onchange for the dropdown and init AJAX in this event.

```
var request = new Ajax.Request(url,{
        method: 'get',
        parameters:{'is_ajax':1},
        onSuccess: function(response){
            data = response.responseText;
            if(!data.isJSON()){
                setLocation(url);
            }

            data = data.evalJSON();
            if (!data.page || !data.blocks){
                setLocation(url);
            }
            amasty_layered_navigation_ajax_update(data);
        },
        onFailure: function(){
            setLocation(url);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: can you specify what specific url should i call?

Comment: Url of your controller, where you'll return JSON response

Comment: @Mark, if it works for you, please set the answer as accepted or add a clarification to the question